# Redis extension Mac OS

Tags: php, macos, redis

I installed Redis extension from [here](https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis). My console see redis installed, when I run `php -i` I see

`redis
Redis Support => enabled
Redis Version => 2.2.7`

When I try to create instance of Redis class I get `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Redis' not found`.

`phpinfo()` shows thay my `php.ini` file is in `/usr/local/php5/lib/php.ini`.

I found solution [here](https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis/issues/468) buy it doesn't work. I also copied extension path from `php-cli ini`.

All extension paths which I tried to use are:

- extension = redis.so
- extension = /usr/local/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/redis.so
- extension = /usr/local/opt/php55-redis/redis.so

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

so strange when you saw Redis but still failed.
Just this line is enough:

```
extension = /usr/local/opt/php55-redis/redis.so
```

Then check `php -v`, make sure no error related to redis happen.

Or try installing by `brew install php55-redis` (I did successfully).

-- note that in OSX El Capitan you have to update brew (`xcode-select --install`)

-- (for Apache) Make sure the php5_module is loaded correctlly:

1. open `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`
2. search for `php5_module`, replace the current path to `/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.xx/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so`
   (5.5.xx is the version when you type `php -v`)

If still failed anyway, restart MAC :((

-- If you install by `brew` but error, give me some comments.

Comment: Nothing... In my opinion it's not working because my php-cli version is 5.5.32, but my apache version is 7.0.2.

Comment: Absolutely apache version is not related to this issue. Make sure the php5_module is loaded correctlly in /etc/apache2/httpd.conf . Possiblly will be: /usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.32/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so. I updated in my answer.

Comment: I have this line with php5_module commented. When I uncomment it and put /usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.32/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so there, my apache stop working.

Comment: Try to make sure that file is existed by open terminal and type : file ...libphp5.so

Comment: I repaired it installing `php70-redis` by `brew`. Thanks for help.

Comment: Congrats :)) happy coding ;)